# Call child views onClickLlistener on clicking on parent view

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I have a `LinearLayout`, which has a selector where it changes its color on click. In the LinearLayout I have two other LinearLayouts (with background color selector).

What I want is the selectors of child LinearLayout to be called when i click on parent LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set duplicateParentState to true in xml layout file for all childs of the the parent being clicked .

Answer (score 0):

select it using

```
findViewById(R.id.childLinearLayout).setSelected(true);
```

You can unselect it using

```
findViewById(R.id.childLinearLayout).setSelected(false);
```